# How update a null date field in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

In a SQLite table I have two fields END_DATE and START_DATE. At fist run END_DATE is empty and null. At second run I want to update previous record where END_DATE is null with current time and create new record but it returns error:

```
     try {
                updateBuilder.where().eq("END_DATE", null);
                updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("END_DATE", currentTime);
                updateBuilder.update();

                   } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

   appUsageLog.setStartDate(currentTime);
            appUsageLog.setPackageName(topPackageName);
            appUsageLog.setEndDate(null);
            appUsageLog.setUser(member);
            try {
                appUsageDao.create(appUsageLog);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

error:

> java.sql.SQLException: argument for 'EndDate' is null

Comment: Can you specify the error you get ?

Comment: Please provide more info, in order to provide a good answer.

Comment: What is the class of `updateBuilder`?  You're going to need to check for `NULL`, and equality probably won't work (at least it won't work semantically directly on SQLite).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'v used ORMLite

Comment: Usually orms provide isNull functions. ORMLite probably does that too. something like where().isNull("END_DATE")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`isNull`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#isNull-java.lang.String-) function to check for `NULL` database values:

```
updateBuilder.where().isNull("END_DATE");
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("END_DATE", currentTime);
updateBuilder.update();
```

As the documentation for `isNull` states, we cannot use equality `=` to check for `NULL` values in SQLite (or really any flavor of SQL):

> Add a 'IS NULL' clause so the column must be null. '=' NULL does not work.